# How to change ng-model of a textbox on change of a radio value?

Tags: angularjs

My textbox looks like this

```
    <input type="number" ng-model="obj.celcius" min="0" max="100" >
```

I have two radio buttons

```
    <input type="radio" ng-model="obj.selection" value="celcius">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="obj.selection" value="farheneit">
```

When the user clicks on the farheneit radio button I want the ng-model of the textbox to change to obj.farheneit. How can I acheive this? I would also like to update min and max of the textbox.

Comment: can you not have something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/PUfnCyVsb3dlrRhuIUnL?p=preview) ?

Comment: Unfortunately no...I have to pass celcius and farheneit to the api. With one of them being null and the other containing a value.

Comment: I'd prefer simple UI stuff over some complicated (like how you're wanting to do) and have object modifications just before calling APIs.. not that what you asked is tough to do, it's way more cleaner (and maintainable?) the other way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `obj[obj.selection]`.

refer below code snippet.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {
      selection: 'celcius',
      celcius: 1,
      farheneit: 2
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="number" ng-model="obj[obj.selection]" min="0" max="100" >
  <input type="radio" ng-model="obj.selection" value="celcius">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="obj.selection" value="farheneit">
  
  {{obj.selection}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created the snippet below. For time being I have added random `min` and `max` values for *Celsius* and *Fahrenheit*.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function($scope) {
  $scope.tempdata = {
    "celsius": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 100,
      "value": 37
    },
    "fahrenheit": {
      "min": 50,
      "max": 150,
      "value": 120
    }
  }
  $scope.upDateData = function(data, type) {
    $scope.obj.temp = data;
    if (type == 'celsius') {
      $scope.min = $scope.tempdata.celsius.min;
      $scope.max = $scope.tempdata.celsius.max;
    } else if (type == 'fahrenheit') {
      $scope.min = $scope.tempdata.fahrenheit.min;
      $scope.max = $scope.tempdata.fahrenheit.max;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.text-data {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
  Number:
  <input type="number" class="text-data" ng-model="obj.temp" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}">
  <div>
    Celsius:
    <input type="radio" ng-model="obj.selection" ng-value="tempdata.celsius.value" ng-change="upDateData(obj.selection, 'celsius')"> Fahrenheit:
    <input type="radio" ng-model="obj.selection" ng-value="tempdata.fahrenheit.value" ng-change="upDateData(obj.selection, 'fahrenheit')">
  </div>
</div>
```